# Saving a model to the database in Django

Tags: python, django, heroku, cron, apscheduler

I am new to django and have been working on a project for a few weeks now. I am making a django application that I host on heroku. I want to schedule a task. The end goal is to make a series of API calls that save the results to a model.

I currently have in my app a file scheduler.py

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
sched = BlockingScheduler()

from fans.models import TotalPageLikes

@sched.scheduled_job('interval',minutes=1)
def timed_job():
    print('This job runs every minute')

@sched.scheduled_job('interval',minutes=1)
def fan_call():
    twr = TotalPageLikes()
    twr.fans = 50
    twr.save()
    print('should have saved TWR')
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        sched.start()
```

In my Procfile I call this

```
web: gunicorn site1.wsgi
scheduler: python manage.py scheduler
```

And here is the model

```
class TotalPageLikes(models.Model):
    fans = models.BigIntegerField()
```

Finally here is my admin

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Fan, Input, TotalPageLikes

admin.site.register(Fan)
admin.site.register(Input)
admin.site.register(TotalPageLikes)
```

Everything deploys and runs successfully, and I can see the results with heroku logs --tail . I see the print statements, but when I open the app in heroku, and navigate to /admin, I see that the model holds nothing. It is not showing an error for the save, but it is not properly saving.

Does anyone know how to save a scheduled job to a model? Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I have tried using TotalPageLikes.objects.create(fans=-1) in scheduler.py and still, it does not show up when I open the app in heroku and navigate to admin. I can see in the log that I am logging it, and I see no error.

**UPDATE**

I ran this locally and it did what I expected it to. Something is occuring with heroku. I have this running on separate dynos because that is how I learned to do this. I am going to attempt to sneak the functions in my models.py to see if this changes anything.

**FINAL UPDATE**
I had to use a PostgreSQL database for this. The necessary steps involved using the command `heroku pg:credentials:url DATABASE` and then setting the proper crednetials from here to my settings.py in DATABASES = . Then I had to create a new superuser `python manage.py createsuperuser` to access my database to confirm it is working.

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with the code. Do you have write access to the database with the user you connected with to the database? Try doing a raw INSERT INTO query yourself to test if you have write access.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I am going to look into this. It is very frustrating.. I am also curious because I restarted this process, and I could not confirm that the task was being run until I realized I had forgotten to do heroku ps:scale scheduler=1 . I now realize that on heroku it is being run on separate dyno's. Could this affect it?

Comment: @engineercoding also, my database is set to dqlite3, not postgreSQL. Could this be affecting it?

Comment: @engineercoding one question, one you describe INSERT INTO are you describing when I am in python manage.py shell to import the model, and then save the model? I am able to do this. I can see an additional save in admin when I do this.